Plotting orbitals on a lattice
I wish to construct a plot where I show various d orbitals on a face-centred cubic lattice. For example, lets say I want to plot two dxy orbitals on two sites of the lattice.
I can plot the lattice as follows:
lattice = ListPointPlot3D[{{0,0,0}, {2,0,0}, {0,2,0}, {2,2,0}, {1,0,1},{2,1,1}, {0,1,1}, {1,2,1}, {0,0,2}, {2,0,2}, {0,2,2}, {2,2,2}, {1,1,0}, {1,1,2}}]

And can plot the dxy orbital as follows:
dxy[\[Theta]_, \[CurlyPhi]_] = SphericalHarmonicY[2, 2, \[Theta], \[CurlyPhi]] - 
         SphericalHarmonicY[2, -2, \[Theta], \[CurlyPhi]] // FullSimplify;
xy = SphericalPlot3D[Abs[dxy[\[Theta], \[CurlyPhi]]]^2, {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> All]

From here I run into two probems: firstly, how would I specify the origin of the dxy orbital? For example I would like two plot on orbital at {0,0,0} and another at {2,0,0}; Secondly, How would I merge the two plots together? I tried to use show[lattice, xy], but that fails to mergethe two plots together.
For context, my end goal is to have a plot that looks a little like this, but in 3D.

What percentage of readers here know what an "FCC lattice" is?  Incidentally, I have a PhD in Physics and don't know what one is.

@DavidG.Stork - just ask the oracle

To answer the second question first, use Show[lattice, xy] with a capital S.
It seems there isn't a nice method to tell SphericalPlot3D to use a different origin. But we can modify the output using a simple replacement rule to move the graphics.  The key is knowing that SphericalPlot3D creates a Graphics3D object, and inserting a GeometricTransformation in the right spot:
ReplaceAll[
    SphericalPlot3D[Abs[dxy[\[Theta], \[CurlyPhi]]] ^ 2,
        {\[Theta], 0, Pi},
        {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 2 * Pi},
        PlotRange -> All
    ],
    Graphics3D[g_, opts___] :> Graphics3D[GeometricTransformation[g, Map[TranslationTransform, pts]],
        opts
    ]
]

where pts is your list of lattice points.

